# Metasploit Ruby Scripting: Problem with framework.db.creds

Tags: metasploit, ruby

I am trying to access the credentials I have gathered so far with Metasploit in a Ruby-Resource script. Unfortunately I get the following error when I try to access `framework.db.creds`.

```
>> framework.db.creds.each
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing    FROM-clause entry for table "hosts"
LINE 1: SELECT "creds".* FROM "creds" WHERE (hosts.workspace_id = 2)
```

When I look into the `creds` table, I see that it is not populated. Instead, I see that credentials are stored in `metasploit_credential_*` tables. The creds method seems to be supported, though...

```
>> framework.db.methods.each do |m|
?> next if ( m !~ /creds/ )
>> print_line("#{m}")
>> end

creds
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a (known) issue with Metasploit? 
I discovered this problem when trying to run the supplied `auto_pass_the_hash.rc` script.

I'm running the following version of Metasploit

```
msf > version
Framework: 4.12.13-dev-202969fae9c0a27bff5c1a82cbe4badb7438036d
Console  : 4.12.13-dev-202969fae9c0a27bff5c1a82cbe4badb7438036d
```

Answer (score 1):

Patch is available at https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/7104. If you are using the Github repo, pull the PR in and test. Otherwise, you will have to wait till the patch is included in the Kali update or MSF Pro/Community versions.